# Check ArrayList contains any specific data

Tags: java

I have an Arraylist:

```
public static ArrayList<ScheduleItem>[] data = (ArrayList<ScheduleItem>[]) new ArrayList[30];
```

Also, I have an another `ArrayList` which contain 3 dates:

```
public static ArrayList<String> dateWay = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now, I want to check if a certain day is in the `data` Arraylist. If not, only then it will parse json file. I tried with this but, It throws null pointer exception

```
if(!ScheduleItem.data[getPageNumber].get(pageNumber).getDate().equals(ScheduleItem.dateWay.get(pageNumber))){
 //method to parse json
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done, may be the method. Or else we will be unable to help you

Comment: `public static ArrayList<ScheduleItem>[] data = 
` is an array of arraylist.

Comment: What is `ScheduleItem`? How do you have date in data array??

Comment: Are you sure that `ScheduleItem.data[getPageNumber]` is not null? How do you populate this array?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. @C.Champagne

Comment: @chetan public String getDate() {
  return date;
 }

 public void setDate(String Date) {
  this.date = date;
 }

Comment: so you need to find if data array contains any ScheduleItem of that date?

Comment: still not sure what you want to achieve. Why do you have array of arralist?

Comment: @chetan Yes. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<ScheduleItem> data = new ArrayList<ScheduleItem>();

Date date = new Date(); //set your date 

for(ScheduleItem item: data){
    if(date.equals(item.getDate()){
         System.out.println("Contains the date");
    }

}
```